# Migrating legacy data to new model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting started with Rails again and am running into a conundrum I find intimidating at the moment. I'm somewhat of a noob when it comes to working with databases, so please forgive me if this is fairly basic.

I have an older Rails app with a data model I no longer wish to conform to. The model should be deprecated in favor of a lighter, less complex one.

The older app is also very monolithic, so I'm trying to break it up into smaller service components.

So this leads me to my question, since it's generally frowned upon to use multiple databases from a single model… what would be the best method for translating data stored in the old model to my new model, one service at a time?

For example, let us suppose I have a user model in both the old and the new. In the old model, the user has many columns, not all of which should make it to the new model.

An example of this could be a change from a user being limited to a single address in the old model to being able to assign a one to many relationship where addresses are split off in their own model and simply referenced using a foreign key or something.

EDIT 1:

The goal ultimately is to siphon the data from the legacy model's database into the new model's database as easily as possible, one dataset at a time.

EDIT 2:

Originally posted from my mobile. Here are a couple examples which may help with suggestions.

**OLD MODEL**

```
  create_table "brands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "logo"
    t.boolean  "verified"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                   null: false
    t.boolean  "hidden",                       default: false
    t.string   "facebook_url"
    t.string   "twitter_handle"
    t.string   "pinterest_handle"
    t.string   "google_plus_url"
    t.string   "address_street1"
    t.string   "address_street2"
    t.string   "address_street3"
    t.string   "address_city"
    t.string   "address_state"
    t.string   "address_zip"
    t.string   "address_country"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "story_title"
    t.text     "story_text"
    t.string   "story_photo"
  end
```

**NEW MODEL**

```
  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "companyName",                               null: false
    t.string   "companyURL",                                null: false
    t.boolean  "companyIsActive",                 default: true,   null: false
    t.boolean  "companyDataIsVerified",           default: false,  null: false
    t.string   "companyLogoFileURL"
    t.datetime "companyFoundedOnDate"
    t.integer  "companyHQLocationID"
    t.integer  "companyParentCompanyID"
    t.integer  "companyFirstSuggestedByID"
    t.string   "companyFacebookURL"
    t.string   "companyGooglePlusURL"
    t.string   "companyInstagramURL"
    t.string   "companyPinterestURL"
    t.string   "companyTwitterURL"
    t.string   "companyStoryTitle"
    t.text     "companyStoryContent"
    t.string   "companyStoryImageFileURL"
    t.boolean  "companyIsHiddenFromIndex",        default: false, null: false
    t.integer  "companyDataScraperID"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                null: false
  end
```

So, basically... I want to be able to take data from the old model, say a brands "name" column and siphon its related values to the new model so the value ends up in the companies "companyName" column of a totally different postgresql instance.

Comment: i think you should first get your new app built and make some custom seed data to help with development. Then when you feel it's complete write a migration script. Writing some automated tests to verify the data fully migrates is important. It's a somewhat rote task but it's gotta get done. Make sure you create records in the right order if there is validation that associated objects exist.

Comment: I have already mapped what columns go where and been testing with custom seed data. Now I just need to move data from old to new and run my tests. Thanks for the reminders and encouragement!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having done this multiple times, I can tell you that the easiest thing to do is to create a simple rake task that iterates the first collection and creates items in the new collection.

There is no need to use anything like DataMapper. You already have ActiveRecord and can simply define which DB connection to use for each model.

In your `config/database.yml`:

```
brand_database:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: brand_host
  username: brand_user
  password: brand_pass
  database: brand_db

company_database:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: company_host
  username: company_user
  password: company_pass
  database: company_db
```

In your models:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :brand_database
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :company_database
end
```

In your new rake task (`lib/tasks/db.rake`):

```
# lib/tasks/db.rake
namespace :db do
  desc "Migrate brand records to company records"
  task :migrate_brands_to_companies, [] => :environment do
    Brand.find_each do |brand|
      Company.find_or_initialize_by(companyName: brand.name) do |company|
        puts "\n\tCreating Company record for #{brand.name}"
        company.companyURL               = brand.url
        company.companyLogoFileURL       = brand.logo
        company.companyTwitterURL        = "https://twitter.com/#{brand.twitter_handle}"
        company.companyIsHiddenFromIndex = brand.hidden
        company.created_at               = brand.created_at
        company.updated_at               = brand.updated_at
        company.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, run the rake task:

```
$ rake db:migrate_brands_to_companies
```

I need to say this: Rails is built using a solid convention. Failing to adhere to that convention will cause problems and additional expense, everytime. I have seen this many many times. Every single time I have seen someone deviate from that convention, they run into far more trouble than they would have ever expected. They break a lot of the "Rails magic".

Comment: This approach works perfectly! Not only do I get to rely on more of Rails' out of the box "magic", but I actually learned about creating custom Rake actions as well!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a TDD approach would certainly help you cover more ground.

Look at [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), which you can use in a Rake task or completely separate Ruby-script.  This way, you can iterate over the app data (from Active Record) and pass it to the new Postgres DB via DataMapper.

You can connect to the new DB like this,

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://user:password@hostname/database')
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using datamapper in this case, considering both OP's apps use activerecord?

Comment: The way I see it, is that the OP can instrument this via the new app, and from what I recall, is that ActiveRecord was designed to always connect to a single DB (However, one could setup a separate top-level class and get a separate AR instance to another DB).

You can then use DataMapper (since it's light-weight) to connect to the second DB, or if you want, use a second AR instance, although I'm not sure how much that's recommended or not.